# Web service (JAX-WS) client in different package

Tags: java, web-services, package, client, jax-ws

Should look like a stupid question, but I have the following problem.
There's an external web service, WSDL is available. My task is to call it's methods from another enterprise application (running on WebSphere 8.5)
Using Rational Application Developer, I generated Web service client classes into the application's project, specifying the application's package, which DIFFERS from the web service's one. Web service's method returns a POJO, which is a wrapper for ArrayList.Then I make a call to web service, using generated calsses in the following way:

```
package com.mycompany.services.external;

import com.mycompany.services.external.client.SomeCommonService;
import com.mycompany.services.external.client.SomeCommonServiceService;
import com.mycompany.services.external.client.IdsList;


    final QName COMMONSERVICE_QNAME = new QName("http://webService.othercompany.com/", "SomeCommonServiceService");

    String strUrl = "http://....";
    String query = "/universal [@Barcode=\"000111\"]";

    URL serviceUrl = new URL(strUrl);
    SomeCommonServiceService service=new SomeCommonServiceService(serviceUrl, COMMONSERVICE_QNAME);
    SomeCommonService port = service.getSomeCommonServicePort();
    IdsList itemsIds = port.getItemsIdsByQuery(query);
```

And as a result the last line of code, where the method is invoked, causes an error:

> [1/17/17 21:55:39:758 MSK] 00000497 SystemErr     R CIWEB Error:
>   [admin(unknown) @ 10.253.32.24]
>   com.ibm.ecm.util.PluginUtil.invokeService()
>   javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:
>   com.mycompany.services.external.client.IdsList is not known to this
>   context

Taking a look into the generated package-info.java the following mapping can be seen:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://webService.othercompany.com/")
package com.mycompany.services.external.client;
```

If I leave original option (not changing default package) while generating client - the same problem and the same error. But in this case, if I pack generated client into a separate JAR and use it as a shared library for my application on WebSphere server - then all works fine! But that's not acceptable for some reasons.

Could somebody be so pleasant to hepl me solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with Web Services Base on WSDL:

Example: http://www.dgii.gov.do/wsMovilDGII/WSMovilDGII.asmx?wsdl

Of course using MAVEN, I use this pluging

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${basedir}/src/main/java/</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>http://www.dgii.gov.do/wsMovilDGII/WSMovilDGII.asmx?wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <packagenames>
                                        <packagename>com.hectorvent.consultadgii</packagename>
                                    </packagenames>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```